# User.Identity.Name always empty in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem using Form Authentication. 
When using IE everything is working fine using Form Authentication. But with firefox and chrome the value for User.Identity.Name and IsAuthenticated is always empty. The scenario is like this I have an ajax call to the controller ($.ajax.....) and in my controller I have their a function that will check if user is Authenticated. When using IE it's fine but with Firefox and Chrome it's not.

Any idea?

Your reply is greatly appreciated.

Best

Answer (score 1):

Are cookies enabled in Firefox and Chrome? Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and when you perform the ajax call verify if the authentication cookie is sent along with the request. The name of the cookie should be specified in the [forms Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) in your web.config file. Also verify if user is authenticated for non-ajax requests.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I mess that point. It's working now.

Best regards,
samer